# alert does not show under the ready event of jquery

Tags: jquery

I am testing JQuery and I have this code in my local computer (which has internet access), but the alert does not show up. Am I missing something obvious?

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body >
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" />
        <script type="text/javascript" > 
            $(document).ready(function(){
                alert("ready");
            });
        </script>
        <div id="message">Hello</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should close the script tag, using `</script>` not `<script ... />`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Flansch Actually the culprit is the invalid markup, this is not a bug in HTML.

Comment: For me the bug is in the specification, the script element is empty, so for what reason should it need a closing tag.